# Is it possible to change values in excel columns based on python dictionaries?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an excel file with multiple columns, with headers such as color, type, location.
It looks something like this (but has many more columns and rows):

| Item | Type | Color | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Ball | Red | Room1 |
| 0002 | Trampoline | Blue | Room1 |

I have another excel file with for each category a number attached to it. For example for color: 1 = Red, 2 = Blue, 3 = Green etc.
I would like to create a new excel file in which each value in the first excel file is replaced by the corresponding number in the key excel file:

| Item | Type | Color | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0002 | 6 | 2 | 1 |

I thought I might be able to use Python to achieve this. I have made separate dictionaries for all categories, e.g. dic_type = {1: Ball, 2: Bottle, 6: Trampoline}. Now I would like to use these dictionaries to change all values in the excel file into the numbers attached to them in the dictionary. I would need to use dic_type for the column 'type', dic_color for 'color' etc. Is there a way to do this with Python?

I'm rather new to Python, but thought this might be more efficient then changing all the numbers by hand in excel.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Fix your formatting please, noone can answer this.

Comment: Sorry, I used the table formatting as suggested, but forgot one enter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read and modify .xlsx files.
Something like

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

color_dict={"green":0,"blue":1,...} 

#open exel sheet
wb = load_workbook(filename = "file_name") # i.e. "file.xlsx"
ws = wb["sheet_name"] # i.e. "Sheet1"
color_column=ws["color_column_nr"] # i.e. "D"

#loop through rows in column
for i, color_name in enumerate(color_column):
    #set the value of given cell to the corresponding number in color_dict (-1 if not present in color_dict)
    ws.cell(row=i,column=color_column_nr).value = color_dict.get(color_name, -1)
```

should work.
But honestly if its just a few entries search and replace in Exel would suffice.